# algorithm to find rescaled zoom and pixel values

Tags: php, algorithm, resize

So I have a requirement where I have a "display-div", which is in SPECIFIC pixel size. Then I will have an image over which a "region-to-display" is marked as  rectangular box. I need to come up with the exact pixel coordinates for top left and bottom right and a zoom in/zoom out value that are required in order to accommodate the region to display inside the "display-div" as good as possible.

for e.g. lets assume:

```
The display-div dimensions are: 100px(width) x 200px(height)

And I have an image that is 2000px(width) x 1000px(height)

Region-to-display is from (1000,500)px (top left of image) 
to (1200,900)px (bottom right of image)
```

So I know that the `width to display is 200px and height to display is 400px`. However `the display-div is 100px x 200px`. So I need to zoom out as well.

Hence I will need to pass data points like:

```
top left = (1000,500)px
bottom right= (1200,900)px
zoom:0.5 (since we need to zoom out)[Firstly is 0.5 even correct??]
```

Now my problem is that I need to formalize this into some kind of "formula" that I can use against any data set, which provided I give the display-div and region-to-display coordinates, will provide me the zoom factor and the pixels for the top left and bottom right coordinates.

Also note that the region-to-display coordinates calculated does not necessarily need to be the same values as the ones marked. In earlier example it is same because the ratio was correct. However sometimes the zoom might be say 1.3 or similar decimal values in which case the region-to-display pixels might differ.

Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Comment: What if the aspect ratios of your div and the region do not match? Do you want to show at least the region (so possibly also parts outside the region) or at most the region (possibly cutting of parts)? And how would your alignment be in that case? Do you want to center? What if your region is on the edge of the picture? I think you need to get your requirements very clear before you can solve this generically.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele - I was only hoping for a generic pseudo-algorithm. However you are right that I need to think through all scenarios. In my case if the aspect ratio has a mismatch and there will be clipping of one side in order to accommodate region of another, then I will see which tradeoff is higher. And ignore that one. For eg, if I need to clip more in order to accommodate few, then I will clip less. And vice versa.